# Can you clone a Perl 6 Proc?

Tags: raku

I was playing with this in 2018.01:

```
my $proc = Proc.new: :out;
my $f = $proc.clone;
$f.spawn: 'ls';
put $f.out.slurp;
```

It says it can't do it. It's curious that the error message is about a routine I didn't use and a different class:

```
Cannot resolve caller stdout(Proc::Async: :bin); none of these signatures match:
    (Proc::Async:D $: :$bin!, *%_)
    (Proc::Async:D $: :$enc, :$translate-nl, *%_)
  in block <unit> at proc-out.p6 line 3
```

Comment: Playing around with this, I noticed that you are defining the named parameter `out` as `True` (the adverb pair without a value defaults to `True`) instead of its default value of `'-'`. When I change `my $proc = Proc.new: :out;` to `my $proc = Proc.new: :out('-');`, I get an output, but the error changes to complaining about `slurp`. Is that what you get, too?

Comment: In the implementation of Proc, when `:out` is defined as `True`, it appends this block onto the `pre-spawn` array: `$stdout-supply = $!proc.stdout(:bin)`, where `$!proc` is of type `Proc::Async`, which is where you get the error you see in the question.

Comment: The docs say :out defaults to `-` and that's how is appears to work. That's not what I want though.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do?

Comment: What I think when I see that message is that you can't clone `stdout`. You can clone processes as long as they don't use singletons such as that one, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Everything inherits a default `clone` method from `Mu`, which does a shallow clone, but that doesn't mean that everything makes sense to clone. This especially goes for objects that might hold references to OS-level things, such as `Proc` or `IO::Handle`. As the person who designed `Proc::Async`, I can say for certain that making it do anything useful on `clone` was not a design consideration. I didn't design `Proc`, but I suspect the same applies.

As for the error, keep in mind that the Perl 6 standard library is implemented in Perl 6 (a lot like in Java and .Net, but less like Perl 5 where many things that are provided by default go directly to something written in C). In this particular case, `Proc` is implemented in terms of `Proc::Async`. Rakudo tries to trim stack traces somewhat to eliminate calls inside of the setting, which is usually a win for the language user, but in cases like this can be a little less helpful. Running Rakudo with the `--ll-exception` flag provides the full details, and thus makes clearer what is going on.

Comment: There are a few problems with this. First, casual users aren't going to know any of the implementation details. Even then, I would expect the implementation to figure it out. Second, if something can't handle the clone it needs to override that in some way to tell the user that.